# get data between two table

Tags: php, pdo

i have to table sql table1 for question and table2 for comment

i want to get post has the largest number of comments

how can to this between two table ??

table question like this

```
id         title   
-----      -------    
1          title1      
2          title2 
3          title3 
4          title4
```

table comment like this

```
id         content     questid
-----      -------     -------- 
1          test         1
2          test         3
2          test         3
2          test         3
```

my code

```
$gquest  = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `question` ORDER BY id DESC");
$gquest->execute(); 
foreach ($gquest->fetchAll() as $rowL)    
{
$cat  = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `questid`=".$rowL['id']."");
$cat->execute();
$cominf = $cat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     
$countquest = $cat->rowCount();  


$gqt  = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `question` ORDER BY ".$cominf['id']." DESC");
$gqt->execute();   
$cfr = $gqt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    


 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what you're looking for from a single query by joining the two tables on the question ID and then `COUNT()` the number of comment occurrences for each question. Here is an example of what it could look like:

```
$gquest  = $DB_con->prepare("
     SELECT q.*, COUNT(c.questid) AS num_comments
     FROM question q
     JOIN comment c
       ON q.id = c.questid
     GROUP BY q.id
     ORDER BY num_comments DESC
     LIMIT 1;
");
```

Here's an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b359e/5)